# Formatting captions in longtable tables

Tags: captions, formatting, longtable

I'm typesetting my dissertation using Springer's `svmono` class. The class defines its own formatting of table and figure captions. I have a couple of multipage tables which I typesetted using longtable package, which has its own `\caption` command which is different than the one imposed by the class (`longtable` uses default formatting of the article class). I'm trying to make the caption formatting consistent, without success so far.

I had a look at LaTeX Companion, but the only information I found there states that

> [with the caption package] it is easy to customize longtable and table
>   captions, keeping the style of captions consistent between those two
>   environments.

I don't find it easy.

Here is a toy example of what I'm looking for.

Link to the [class `svmonomb`](http://bojan.3e.pl/etc/svmonomb.cls)

```
\documentclass{svmonomb}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

I would like to have the longtable version \ref{longtable} look like 
the ``normal'' version \ref{table}.

\bigskip

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption of the normal \texttt{table} environment.}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrr}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \caption{Caption of the \texttt{longtable} environment.}
    \label{longtable}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please create a minimal compilable example. Also, it would be good if you link to classes which are not on CTAN. E.g. `svmono` seems to live here: http://www.springer.com/authors/book+authors?SGWID=0-154102-12-417900-0

Comment: Since I'm the author of the caption package I am very interested why you don't find it easy. I always try to improve the documentation, but am dependent on input, especially on what is not comprehensible, so I can change it (hopefully) for the better.

Comment: @Martin-Scharrer Sorry, you are perfectly right. Because I tempered with the `svmono` a little bit here is my modified version (http://bojan.3e.pl/etc/svmonomb.cls).

Comment: @Axel, caption's documentation is pretty clear how to create custom `\caption` commands. The problem is that the captions in the longtable package are different animals than the captions defined in, say, article class. I believe they are kind of `\multicolumn` commands. I'll try to post a small example in a moment.

Comment: Yes, longtable captions are different, and wrapfigure, and many other captions, too. But the caption package patches them all so a single macro is used for the typesetting of the captions, so all should have the same look & feel when using the caption package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility would be using the caption package:

```
\documentclass{svmonomb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[small,bf,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\begin{document}

I would like to have the longtable version \ref{longtable} look like 
the ``normal'' version \ref{table}.

\bigskip

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption of the normal \texttt{table} environment.}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrr}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \caption{Caption of the \texttt{longtable} environment.}
    \label{longtable}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

A different option would be redefining `\LT@caption` similar to the code of `\@makecaption` (which can be found inside svmonomb.cls).

Comment: @Alex, thanks a million! I did not know that your package works that way (perhaps I should have tried first). Anyway, thanks again.