# Longtable - aligning caption to left

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formating captions in longtable tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/formating-captions-in-longtable-tables)

Is it possible to align longtable caption to the left side of paper ? Standard table and tabular command align caption to the left and I would like to achieve the same effect in longtable. Is it possible ??

Comment: `longtable` centers the caption by default by using `\multicolumn{<num>}{c}{...}` internally. This seems to be hardcoded. But the manual states that you can use the `caption` package to change this.

Comment: This should be answered by [Formating captions in longtable tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/formating-captions-in-longtable-tables). Using `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}` works for me.

Answer (score 4):

As Martin noted, use the `caption` package. It has options to change the formatting of the caption. To left align the caption for all tables use the package option `singlelinecheck=off`. I've used data from the example in [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21836/5701) to construct the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Wyniki rozpoznawania obrazów dla obrazu zapytania 004\_0001.jp w katalogu baseballbat}\\\hline
054\_0020.jpg & 209 & ring &054\_0020.jpg & 209 & 10089.1  & celu & time & 0.98  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, @N.N., but this doesn't work! Try reducing the caption to two words and you will see that it gets centered. The `justification=raggedright` doesn't has any effect here. I did the same MWE and figured you need (only!) `singlelinecheck=off` as shown in [Formating captions in longtable tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/formating-captions-in-longtable-tables), which makes it close enough to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer True, `singlelinecheck=off` works with short captions (and I've changed my answer accordingly). They – `justification=raggedright` and `singlelinecheck=off` – have almost the same effect on long captions though.

Comment: `singlelinecheck=off` has no effect on long captions at all (since it only affects "short" resp. "single-line" captions). `justification=raggedright` has clearly an effect since it changes the justification of the text from `justified` to `raggedright`. So I would say, no, the above statement that both have almost the same effect on long captions is IMHO not correct.