# longtable - strange lines at the end of table

Tags: tables, longtable, rules

I have strange problem with longtable package. Almost all my tables looks great but some of  have strange lines at the end of tables. Please take a look at the picture

I create the table like that

```
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Wyniki rozpoznawania obrazów dla obrazu zapytania 004\_0001.jp w katalogu baseballbat}\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Obraz zapytanie}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Obraz przetwarzany}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Wynik}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Nazwa} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Katalog} & \textbf{Nazwa} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{J} & \textbf{J} & \textbf{Czas} & \textbf{Gęstość} \\ \hline
054\_0020.jpg & 209 & ring &054\_0020.jpg & 209 & 10089.1  & celu & time & 0.98  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0002.jpg & 288 & 21585.7  & celu & time & 0.52  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0013.jpg & 213 & 10755.7  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0004.jpg & 250 & 15510.8 & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0011.jpg & 117 &  3599.62  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0015.jpg & 256 & 13359.8  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0019.jpg & 275 & 20456.9  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0026.jpg & 209 & 7813.75  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0028.jpg & 130 & 3307.91  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0029.jpg & 275 & 17064.3 & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0037.jpg & 95  & 5653.98  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0041.jpg & 234 & 9418.73  & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0042.jpg & 120 & 2643.69 & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
                  &  & ring  &054\_0044.jpg & 114 & 2672.92 & celu & time & 0.43  \\ \hline
\label{tab:ring}
\end{longtable}
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this code , that it produces this strange line

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This could also be caused by some other package which interferes with `longtable`. Please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the `\label{tab:ring}` at the end. It creates a new row, but only one column, so only the vertical lines of this column are drawn. You need to place it somewhere else, at best direct after `\caption` (but never before it) or in the `firsthead` (as the manual says) or as part of another box, before the last `\\ \hline` should be fine.