# longtable: change table caption location

Tags: captions, longtable, pgfplotstable

I want to read a csv file and create a multi-page table using `\longtable`.
I need to place the caption *after* the table. When the table is small and fits in one page, it works (the first table in the MWE). However, when I have a multi-page table, the caption is placed very close to the table (the second example). When I use `\tabularnewline` or `\\[0.2in]` to add some space between the table and the caption, 2 out of 3 vertical lines in the table increase their size and "exit" from the table.

When I load the `caption` package and set `belowskip=20pt`, I have correct caption location for the multi-page table, but the short table's caption becomes too far from the table. I need to have both tables with correct caption location in the document.

I also tried the `etoolbox` package with `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}` as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164154/longtable-caption-formatting), but did not get the desired output.

How can I fix the multi-page table and have more space between the table and the caption without affecting the short table's caption?

Here are [short and long table data files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qq902polz534mbn/data.zip?dl=0), and my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,times]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=20pt, position=top}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

%% Correct table
\paragraph{Table \ref{tab:correct} is correct.} There is some space between the table and the caption.
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  every head row/.style={
    before row={
      \hline & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bf 3 Cols}\\
    },
    after row=\hline,
  },
  every last row/.style={
    after row=\hline,
  },
  columns/col1/.style={
    column name={\bf Col1},
    column type={|l|},
    string type,
  },
  columns/col2/.style={
    column name={\bf Col2},
    column type={c},
    string type,
  },
  columns/col3/.style={
    column name={\bf Col3},
    column type={c},
    string type,
  },
  columns/col4/.style={
    column name={\bf Col4},
    column type={c|},
    string type,
  },
]{data-short.csv}
\end{center}
\caption{This table has ``correct'' caption location.}
\label{tab:correct}
\end{table}


%% Incorrect
\paragraph{Table \ref{tab:incorrect} is Incorrect.} The caption is attached to the table. There should be some space between the table and the caption as in Table \ref{tab:correct}.
%\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
  every head row/.style={
    before row={
      \hline & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bf 3 Cols}\\
    },
    after row=\hline,
  },
  every last row/.style={
    after row={
      \hline
      %\tabularnewline
      %\\[0.2in]
      \caption{\normalsize \mbox{This table has ``incorrect'' caption location. It is attached to the table.}}
      \label{tab:incorrect}
      },
  },
  columns/col1/.style={
    column name={\bf Col1},
    column type={|l|},
    string type,
  },
  columns/col2/.style={
    column name={\bf Col2},
    column type={l},
    string type,
  },
  columns/col3/.style={
    column name={\bf Col3},
    column type={c},
    string type,
  },
  columns/col4/.style={
    column name={\bf Col4},
    column type={c|},
    string type,
  },
]{data-long.csv}
\end{center}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the extra spacing for the caption in the `table` environment is caused by the use of the `center` environment. In general this is discouraged because of this additional space (both above and below the table). Instead the use of the `\centering` command is recommended, but then the caption in the first table is also too close to the table. But see below how to solve this.

As you are using the `caption` package, you can use

```
\captionsetup[longtable]{position=bottom,skip=20pt}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom,skip=20pt}
```

Or whatever amount you prefer.

Comment: Inside a `longtable` the  `caption` package utilizes both, first the `table` and afterwards the `longtable` options. So `\captionsetup[table]{...}` is sufficient in this case.

Comment: OK, I didn't know. I suppose they don't add up :)