# Make longtable captions single spaced using memoir class

Tags: captions, memoir, longtable, line-spacing

I am having a nightmare trying to solve this problem. It seems standard captions for figures and tables using memoir class are single spaced, but for tables created using longtable package they are double spaced. I can't make these single spaced using caption + setspace as memoir class doesn't load setspace, using its own code for baseline spacing and scaling (as I understand it). The most promising post I found was this one: 
[Longtable Caption Spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428023/longtable-caption-spacing)

I think it is suggesting to change the longtable.sty file in the latex distribution - adding \singlespacing??? If I'm correct, I have now done this but nothing is changing and the captions remain double spaced.

Any suggestions would be warmly welcome - been at this for a good couple of days.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\OnehalfSpacing

\lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Table very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table}
    \end{table}

\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{llll}
        \caption{Longtable very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption} \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        \label{longtable}
    \end{longtable}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
    \begin{longtable}[htbp]{lcclcl}

        \caption[Specimen Collection]{Specimen information including species name, institution accession or record number, sex of specimen, host species name, year the specimen was collected, and location it was collected. Sex: F = Female, M = Male, j. = juvenile, t. = transitionary stage.}
        \label{table:museo} \\ \toprule

        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Species}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acc./Record} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Host}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year Collected} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Location} \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}


    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You'll see in tables 2 and 3 the caption line spacing is 1.5, whereas, using a normal table, table 1 is single spaced. I've now changed back the longtable.sty file as that solution didn't work anyway.

EDIT: All Packages

```
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} 

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\GIANT{\@setfontsize\Huge{20}{0}}
\makeatother  

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\GIANT}

\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\usepackage{url} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{color, colortbl} 

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}

\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, headsep=40pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array,calc}

%\usepackage{setspace} doesn't work with memoir???

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{natbib}
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})} %adds possessive citation \cites{}
\newcommand{\citeay}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}} % comman in citealt
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
```

Comment: I should clarify I want the actual table spacing to be 1.5 - it's only the caption I want to alter

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with your current line spacing settings and as well as an example longtable?

Comment: Please do not directly change the `.sty`file of an existing package.

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\makeatletter\patchcmd\LT@makecaption{\sbox}{\singlespacing\sbox}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}\makeatother` in the preamble should work (untested though, due to lacking MWE).

Comment: @Skillmon - this doesn't seem to work. I saw another etoolbox solution that also failed - maybe it isn't loaded by memoir either???

Comment: You need load `etoollbox` yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko even with \usepackage{etoolbox} this solution doesn't work

Comment: Do you use the `caption` package? Can you please show which packages you're using that could change captions?

Comment: Ok, the issue was the `caption` package, so my edited answer should work.

Comment: Unrelated: Using `\PassOptionsToPackage` must be used before the package is actually loaded, so `\usepackage{url}\PassOptionsToPackage{...}{url}`. Also `hyperref` should be loaded last (except for a few exceptions), loading `color` after `xcolor` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a (in my opinion) better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nice hack 1 (or ‘hack-patch 1’)**

After some tinkering, I discover a (hopefully) better solution. Instead of manipulating `\baselinestretch` I suggest using the `\fontsize{<fontsize>}{<leading>}`-command. It is just to reset the the font size to the caption's fontsize (here 12 pt) and use the second parameter to create the single spacing. LaTeX normally set 20 per cent leading, so the correct command should be `\fontsize{12}{13.2}\selectfont}`. However, you may compress the caption by using 12 pt or 12.5 pt leading.

Using the `\fontsize`-command, you do not need to set the optional `[Short caption]`.

In addition, I suggest defining a shorthand, `\sspace` so you can change leading one place. Maybe this even deserves to be called a patch, or at least a ‘hack-patch’ or ‘patch-hack’, since I use a font command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\newcommand{\sspace}{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont} 

\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\OnehalfSpacing

\lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{\sspace Table very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption.}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table}
    \end{table}

\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{llll}
        \caption{\sspace Longtable very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption.} \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        \label{longtable}
    \end{longtable}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
    \begin{longtable}[htbp]{lcclcl}

        \caption{\sspace Specimen information including species name, institution accession or record number, sex of specimen, host species name, year the specimen was collected, and location it was collected. Sex: F = Female, M = Male, j. = juvenile, t. = transitionary stage.}
        \label{table:museo} \\ \toprule

        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Species}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acc./Record} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Host}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year Collected} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Location} \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}


    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**Crude hack 1**

Here is a crude hack that works, add `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont`to the caption. For some reason, you must set the optional short captions [Long caption]:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\OnehalfSpacing

\lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Table very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table}
    \end{table}

\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{llll}
        \caption[Long Caption]{\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont Longtable very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption} \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        \label{longtable}
    \end{longtable}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
    \begin{longtable}[htbp]{lcclcl}

        \caption[Specimen Collection]{\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont Specimen information including species name, institution accession or record number, sex of specimen, host species name, year the specimen was collected, and location it was collected. Sex: F = Female, M = Male, j. = juvenile, t. = transitionary stage.}
        \label{table:museo} \\ \toprule

        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Species}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acc./Record} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Host}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year Collected} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Location} \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}


    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both answers work with my MWE but for some reason @Skillmon 's solution doesn't work in my actual document, hence the using this as the accepted answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: @CharlesBaillie if my answer doesn't work in your actual document, can you please provide a list of packages you're using, so I can take a look. I don't think that using this answer is the proper approach and that correctly fixing it is the way to go.

Comment: @Skillmon If a solution works, why is it not a proper approach. It is clean, simple and transparent. If you have hundreds of longtables, I agree that a complicated patch may seem to be better, but the risk is that the patch breaks when you load a new, or updated, package. If you have hundreds of longtables, of cause you define a shortcut to implement my solution, and then you can change the definition of the shortcut at one place. Often, good enough is the best.

Comment: @Sveinung I beg to disagree, there shouldn't be any general formatting macros inside the caption necessary. The LaTeX-way of things would be to change the definition of `\LT@makecaption` such that it is correct, not to include some macro in every argument of said macro. So while I agree that your answer solves the issue at hand, it doesn't solve it in a proper LaTeX-y approach.

Comment: @Skillmon Well, your patch add a command inside the caption, too, and is a hack, exactly as my solution. The only "proper" LaTeX solution would be that the package authors change the packages.

Comment: @Sveinung my answer is a patch, not a hacky solution. My answer has to be used once, yours every time. This is nothing personal or anything like that. My solution is just a lot cleaner (or rather would be if I knew the interfering code) and this can be judged in an objective manner.

Comment: @Skillmon This is your personal opinion, mine is that both solutions are hacking. "Patching" only seems to be a prettier word.

Comment: @Skillmon answer edited with all packages

Answer (score 2):

The following patches `\LT@makecaption` at the correct point with the correct information for your MWE. Problem is that the macro is getting redefined and this removes the patch. If we patch `\AtBeginDocument` this should work, also we don't search for `\sbox` as the new definition doesn't use `\sbox` but we use `\let` as that is the first token inside the `\parbox` which surrounds the caption:

**EDIT:** I changed the answer a bit to so that it works whether the `caption` package is loaded or not. It could still fail if you use other packages which redefine `\LT@makecaption`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument
  {%
    \@ifpackageloaded{caption}
      {%
        \patchcmd\LT@makecaption{\caption@@make}{\SingleSpacing\caption@@make}
      }
      {%
        \patchcmd\LT@makecaption{\let}{\SingleSpacing\let}
      }
      {}{\errmessage{patch failed!}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\OnehalfSpacing

\lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \caption{Table very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
            1 & 1 & 1 & 1
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table}
    \end{table}

\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{llll}
        \caption{Longtable very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption} \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        \label{longtable}
    \end{longtable}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
    \begin{longtable}[htbp]{lcclcl}

        \caption[Specimen Collection]{Specimen information including species name, institution accession or record number, sex of specimen, host species name, year the specimen was collected, and location it was collected. Sex: F = Female, M = Male, j. = juvenile, t. = transitionary stage.}
        \label{table:museo} \\ \toprule

        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Species}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acc./Record} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sex} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Host}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Year Collected} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Location} \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}


    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solutions - I actually understand where the redefinition is occurring now!!!! Also, thanks for the philosophical discussion with @Sveinung. I'll stick with the answer I accepted first, but agree that this one is more elegant (only having to patch once rather than in each caption) at least where other packages don't redefine caption spacing.

Comment: @CharlesBaillie It should not be a big issue to change Skillmon's ha.. , sorry, patch so that it put the commands I suggest into the beginning of the caption.

Comment: @Sveinung there is no need for that. The current form of the answer should work in his document.

Comment: @Skillmon Then I misunderstood Charles Baillie's comment.

Comment: @Sveinung he didn't comment that it doesn't work currently (as I understood), but that he fears it'll cease to work if he loads other packages as well, and therefore sticks with your answer.

Comment: @Skillmon As I said, I misunderstood. I removed the combination of your and mine solution, and instead improved my solution by using the `\fontsize` command.