# How to make the longtable to work with centering & caption on memoir class?

Tags: longtable

I am trying to use `memoir` class with `longtable` environment, but no success:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption of the normal \texttt{table} environment.}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Do the error:

```
 test2.tex:7: Class memoir Error:  Illegal pream-token (\centering): `c' used. [    \centering]
```

Changing `longtable` by `table` does work correctly with no errors or warnings. How to make the `longtable` to also work?

---

Related questions:

1. [How can I make a table that takes up more than a single page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page)
2. [Make a table span multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/make-a-table-span-multiple-pages)
3. [Formatting captions in longtable tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/formatting-captions-in-longtable-tables)

Comment: Do you need `longtable`?

Comment: Well, the table by itself does not fit in only one page. So would be nice if it split by itself.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with [`longtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/longtable) by using the example code at the end of the [`longtable` doumentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf).

Comment: @Werner, the one at the page 10?

Comment: Indeed. Start there, and remove the content you don't need, and change whatever you want to keep. You won't see the construction you started with. Starting with the documentation is always good.

Comment: longtable has the same syntax as tabular, you need to specify the columns with `{ccccccc}` or some such argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\centering` is automatic for long tables, and the caption is part of the environment. So try with this syntax:

```
\begin{longtable}{*{8}{c}}
    \caption{Caption of the normal \texttt{table} environment.}
    \label{table}\\
  \endfirsthead
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\tablename~\thetable\enspace(continued)}\\
  \endhead
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{longtable}
```