# Longtable and tabular caption vertical and horizontal alignment

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, alignment

My problem is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/formatting-captions-in-longtable-tables), the caption alignment of tabular table and longtable is different. I would like to have the caption to be consistent with the tabular form, with some white padding from the top margin and align to the left of the toprule. I have tried to use [singlelinecheck=off] as suggested but it didn
t change anything. Then I want to try redefining the \LT@caption as suggested as another way but I have no idea how to redefine it to make it as the tabular one.

I am guessing some of the problem may be related to my preset margin but it didn't align correctly even when I remove the a4paper setting. Any help or insight would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=0.05cm, hmargin=0.1cm, marginparwidth=0.1cm,total={210mm,297mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, xcolor}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage{longtable}


\newlength{\mylength} \settowidth{\mylength}{$-55.55\pm0.55$}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\notsotiny{\@setfontsize\notsotiny{6.5}{7.5}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
    \sisetup{
        table-number-alignment=center,
        separate-uncertainty=true,
        table-column-width = 2cm,
        table-format =-2.2,
        separate-uncertainty,
        table-figures-uncertainty=1, table-space-text-post=(16)}
    \begin{ThreePartTable} 
        \notsotiny
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.3pt}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.2pt}
        \begin{longtable}{>{\itshape}p{2cm}p{0.8cm}@{}*{12}{S}@{}}%
            \caption{Taxon}\\
                \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Site} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SL} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EI} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-14}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Season}& {Wet} &{Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {\makebox[\mylength]{Dry}} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Species}}   & Tracer & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} \\
        \midrule
            \endfirsthead
    \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}}& $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       & 12.82\pm0.36\ts{(4)} &       &       & 13.83\pm0.99\ts{(8)} & 14.25\pm0.49\ts{(2)} & 14.60\pm0.23\ts{(4)} &  \\
& $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       & -16.73\pm0.29\ts{(4)} &       &       & -16.62\pm0.27\ts{(8)} & -17.30\pm0.14\ts{(2)} & -16.65\pm0.31\ts{(4)} &  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{longtable}
        \end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{landscape}
    \begin{landscape}
        \sisetup{
        table-number-alignment=center,
        separate-uncertainty=true,
        table-column-width = 2cm,
        table-format =-2.2,
        separate-uncertainty,
        table-figures-uncertainty=1, table-space-text-post=(16)}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable} 
        \notsotiny
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.3pt}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.2pt}
        \caption{Taxon}
        \begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}p{2cm}p{0.8cm}@{}*{12}{S}@{}}%
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Site} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SL} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EI} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-14}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Season}& {Wet} &{Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {\makebox[\mylength]{Dry}} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Species}}   & Tracer & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}}& $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       & 12.82\pm0.36\ts{(4)} &       &       & 13.83\pm0.99\ts{(8)} & 14.25\pm0.49\ts{(2)} & 14.60\pm0.23\ts{(4)} &  \\
        & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       & -16.73\pm0.29\ts{(4)} &       &       & -16.62\pm0.27\ts{(8)} & -17.30\pm0.14\ts{(2)} & -16.65\pm0.31\ts{(4)} &  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `threeparttableex` package you could give the `floatrow` package and its longtable option `LTcapwidth=content` a try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=0.05cm, hmargin=0.1cm, marginparwidth=0.1cm,total={210mm,297mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, xcolor}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=contents}


\newlength{\mylength} \settowidth{\mylength}{$-55.55\pm0.55$}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\notsotiny{\@setfontsize\notsotiny{6.5}{7.5}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
    \sisetup{
        table-number-alignment=center,
        separate-uncertainty=true,
        table-column-width = 2cm,
        table-format =-2.2,
        separate-uncertainty,
        table-figures-uncertainty=1, table-space-text-post=(16)}
%    \begin{ThreePartTable} 
        \notsotiny
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.3pt}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.2pt}
        \begin{longtable}[c]{>{\itshape}p{2cm}p{0.8cm}@{}*{12}{S}@{}}%
            \caption{Taxon}\\
                \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Site} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SL} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EI} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-14}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Season}& {Wet} &{Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {\makebox[\mylength]{Dry}} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Species}}   & Tracer & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} \\
        \midrule
            \endfirsthead
    \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}}& $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       & 12.82\pm0.36\ts{(4)} &       &       & 13.83\pm0.99\ts{(8)} & 14.25\pm0.49\ts{(2)} & 14.60\pm0.23\ts{(4)} &  \\
& $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       & -16.73\pm0.29\ts{(4)} &       &       & -16.62\pm0.27\ts{(8)} & -17.30\pm0.14\ts{(2)} & -16.65\pm0.31\ts{(4)} &  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{longtable}
%        \end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{landscape}
    \begin{landscape}
        \sisetup{
        table-number-alignment=center,
        separate-uncertainty=true,
        table-column-width = 2cm,
        table-format =-2.2,
        separate-uncertainty,
        table-figures-uncertainty=1, table-space-text-post=(16)}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable} 
        \notsotiny
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.3pt}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.2pt}
        \caption{Taxon}
        \begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}p{2cm}p{0.8cm}@{}*{12}{S}@{}}%
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Site} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{WO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SL} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EO} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EI} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-14}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Season}& {Wet} &{Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {Dry} & {Wet} & {\makebox[\mylength]{Dry}} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{{Species}}   & Tracer & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} & {Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} &{Mean $ \pm$ SD $_{(n)}$} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{{Genus}\\ { Species}}}& $\delta{^{15}}$N &       &       &       &       &       & 12.82\pm0.36\ts{(4)} &       &       & 13.83\pm0.99\ts{(8)} & 14.25\pm0.49\ts{(2)} & 14.60\pm0.23\ts{(4)} &  \\
        & $\delta{^{13}}$C &       &       &       &       &       & -16.73\pm0.29\ts{(4)} &       &       & -16.62\pm0.27\ts{(8)} & -17.30\pm0.14\ts{(2)} & -16.65\pm0.31\ts{(4)} &  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,it works perfectly although I don't know what is the reason behind. So is there a conflict between longtable and threeparttableex so that the caption is not displayed correctly in my original example?

Comment: @JasonYau The `threeparttable` offers two features for tables: Table notes (optional) and a caption width identical to the width of the table. Although the `threeparttablex` is a similar package for longtables, it offers table notes only. So if you want to start the caption on the same horizontal position as your table, `threeparttablex` is not sufficient. Instead you need either a package which offers the "caption width identical to the width of the table" feature for longtables (like `floatrow`) or a package which allows setting extra margins for captions of longtables (like `caption`).